# Memory-efficient dummy values in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary, set, trie, singleton-type

If I have maps of keys to values then sets of keys can be implemented as maps of keys to fixed dummy values.

There are many candidates for dummies:

- `data`-defined types without constructors
- other uninhabited types (e.g. `forall a . a`)
- singleton types
- unboxed types

The most obvious solution to me is to use a stock singleton type `()` but with `case` I can distinguish `()` from bottom, so I think memory representation of `()` includes indirections.

I have 2 questions:

- Does `Map.fromList [(1, ()), (2, ())]` take more memory than `let dummy = () in Map.fromList [(1, dummy), (2, dummy)]`?
- What value is recommended for `dummy` to construct sets out of [bytestring-trie](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring-trie/0.1.4/doc/html/Data-Trie.html), considering memory footprint, cpu usage and correctness?

Comment: Every concrete `()` in your program should evaluate to

Comment: "but with case I can distinguish () from bottom" no you can't. `case undefined of () -> do{foo}; _ -> do{bar}` will _not_ evaluate to `bar`, but throw an exception. Of course you can wrap it in ugly unsafe IO nets to catch the undefined, but that really can't be the right solution to any problem.

Comment: I believe that GHC uses a single instance for every constructor with no arguments (E.g. Nothing, True, False, () etc), so the memory usage is amortised over all their uses everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keys will all be (represented as) pointers pointing to a single allocated `()` constructor.

Answer (score 11):

Nullary constructors are allocated only once. All their uses are then shared (in GHC; this behaviour is not dictated by the Haskell standard).

The `()` is a nullary constructor of the unit type `()`. So using `()` all over the place hardly costs any memory. If you instantiate a type parameter to `()`, you will still pay for the presence of that parameter, though. That's why for example there is a specialized `Set a` instead of using `Map a ()`.

For a key-value data structure, you want a type with a proper value. Therefore, `()` is the right choice, and empty data types are not. A polymorphic type such as `forall a. a` would additionally need to be wrapped in another datatype or requires impredicativity if used as an argument, which is generally not well supported.